# Two processes have different behavior while running with the same command and same binary file

Tags: ubuntu, process, ffmpeg

There's an app in Ubuntu server, which runs a FFMPEG instance. That instance keeps working fine.

But when I run the same command with the same binary executable in terminal, it exits after 3 or 4 minutes with log 'Conversion failed!'.

Both processes are run as root user, and also using same `.so` libraries.

I also viewed environment variables of the correct process with `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/62243/environ`:

```
LANG=en_US
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
USER=root
SHELL=/bin/sh
INVOCATION_ID=89a8c6c4b24d4a1b919e0cf529366876
JOURNAL_STREAM=9:308
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/_MEIDvDVDH
AV_LOG_FORCE_COLOR=
AV_LOG_FORCE_256COLOR=
```

I created a shell script to set environment variables before my command:

```
export var1=value
export var2=value
export var3=value
.
.
.
my_command_here
```

Still problem exists.

I can't find out why. And it's become a headache.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Increase log verbosity

Comment: @Gerald Schneider I run it with maximum logs `-loglevel 51`. It only says one thing at the end: Conversion failed!

Comment: Do both processes run at the same time?

Comment: @paladin No. Same thing happens even if they don't run at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can run `strace ffmpeg` and see what system call is calling when the  program aborted to get more information.

As to the problem, I guess it may due to the resource(e.g. memory) is not enough to run the second program?